# Can I create multiple instances of oracle DB on the same ASM instance?

Tags: oracle, instance, restart

Right now I have an ASM instance on which a single oracle instance is running.

Can I create one more DB instance on the same ASM instance?

Comment: yes, you can. You can have more than one database using the same ASM instance,  ASM is installed under grid infrastructure, and provide management storage to as many databases as your hardware is able to deal with

Comment: [assembly] is for assembly language, like `add w0, w0, w1` (AArch64).  I don't know what ASM means in this question, so I didn't add any tag to replace it.  If there is an appropriate one, it should be added.

Comment: _" I don't know what ASM means in this question"_    It is the common acronym for oracle's Advanced Storage Management.

Comment: Yes. Typically one ASM per host and of course, as many DB's as you like on a host

Comment: Thanks @RobertoHernandez and Connor, for answering my questions so promptly